# iOS 12: Is there no longer any way to debug a PWA?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

In some ways, PWA support is better in iOS 12 than in previous versions. But one very disconcerting change is that I no longer seem to be able to debug via Safari on my Mac.

In particular, I would like to examine console logging at the points where the PWA launches and restores the last view before previously closed. But there are other PWA peculiarities that make debugging inside Safari (as opposed to standalone) far too limiting.

Does anyone know how I can use web inspector (or something like it) with PWAs on iOS 12 and above?

**UPDATE OCT 1 2019**
With iOS 13, Apple has brought back debugging in Safari.